# When I edit an xml in Java, the updated xml contains xmlns=""

Tags: java, xml

I have an xml file where I need to edit the values for some attributes. When I remove attributes and add again the same attributes using new values, the result
contains `xmlns=""`.

Initial xml:

```
<ClinicalDocument xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" classCode="DOCCLIN" moodCode="EVN" xmlns:pharm="urn:hl7-org:pharm" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <realmCode code="CY"/>
    <typeId extension="POCD_HD000040" root="2.16.840.1.113883.1.3"/>
    <templateId root="1.3.6.1.4.1.12559.11.10.1.3.1.1.2"/>
    <templateId root="1.3.6.1.4.1.19376.1.5.3.1.1.1"/>
    <id extension="1.2.3.4.5.6" root="2.16.840.1.113883.3.9143.3.1.3"/>
    <code code="60593-1" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.1" codeSystemName="LOINC" codeSystemVersion="2.59" displayName="Medication dispensed.extended Document">
        <translation code="60593-1" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.1" codeSystemName="LOINC" displayName="eDispensation"/>
    </code>
    <title>Medication dispensed</title>
    <effectiveTime value="20221130152655+0000"/>
    <confidentialityCode code="N" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.5.25" codeSystemName="Confidentiality" codeSystemVersion="913-20091020" displayName="normal"/>
    <languageCode code="en-GB"/>
    <setId extension="22015711.1" root="2.16.840.1.113883.3.9143.3.1.3"/>
    <recordTarget>
        <patientRole classCode="PAT">
            <id extension="x1x2x2" root="2.16.840.1.113883.2.25.3.4.1.1.2"/>
            <addr>
                <country>GR</country>
                <streetAddressLine>ΕΓΝΑΤΙΑ 10</streetAddressLine>
            </addr>
            <telecom use="H" value="tel:12344"/>
            <patient>
                <name>
                    <given>MARINA</given>
                    <family>FILIP</family>
                </name>
                <administrativeGenderCode code="F" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.5.1" codeSystemName="AdministrativeGender" codeSystemVersion="913-20091020" displayName="Female"/>
                <birthTime value="20150101"/>
                <languageCommunication>
                    <templateId root="1.3.6.1.4.1.19376.1.5.3.1.2.1"/>
                    <languageCode code="en-GB"/>
                </languageCommunication>
            </patient>
        </patientRole>
    </recordTarget>
</ClinicalDocument>
```

Code:

```
String eD = "previous_xml_value".
                
DocumentBuilder db = null;
try {
    db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
} catch (ParserConfigurationException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
InputSource is = new InputSource();
is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(eD));

Document doc = null;
try {
    doc = db.parse(is);
} catch (SAXException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}


// Change info from eD to create eD discard
NodeList node_to_change_code_id_title = doc.getElementsByTagName("ClinicalDocument");
Element element_to_change_code_id_title = null;
NodeList eD_id_to_set_eD_id = null;
Element eD_id_extension = null;

NodeList eD_id_to_set_eD_code = null;
Element eD_set_code = null;
NodeList eD_id_to_set_eD_title = null;
Element eD_set_title = null;

if (node_to_change_code_id_title.getLength()> 0) {
    element_to_change_code_id_title = (Element) node_to_change_code_id_title.item(0);
    
    eD_id_to_set_eD_id = element_to_change_code_id_title.getElementsByTagName("id");
    eD_id_extension = (Element) eD_id_to_set_eD_id.item(0);
    eD_id_extension.removeAttribute("extension");
    eD_id_extension.setAttribute("extension", discard_eD_id_full);
    
    eD_id_to_set_eD_code = element_to_change_code_id_title.getElementsByTagName("code");
    eD_set_code = (Element) eD_id_to_set_eD_code.item(0);
    eD_set_code.setAttribute("xmlns", "urn:hl7-org:v3");
    eD_set_code.removeAttribute("code");
    eD_set_code.setAttribute("code", "DISCARD-60593-1");
    eD_set_code.removeAttribute("codeSystem");
    eD_set_code.setAttribute("codeSystem", "2.16.840.1.113883.6.1");
    eD_set_code.removeAttribute("codeSystemName");
    eD_set_code.setAttribute("codeSystemName", "LOINC");
    eD_set_code.removeAttribute("displayName");
    eD_set_code.setAttribute("displayName", "Discard Medication Dispensed");
    
    eD_id_to_set_eD_title = element_to_change_code_id_title.getElementsByTagName("title");
    eD_set_title = (Element) eD_id_to_set_eD_title.item(0);
    eD_set_title.setTextContent("Discard Medication Dispensed");
}
```

This is the result:

```
<ClinicalDocument xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:pharm="urn:hl7-org:pharm" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" classCode="DOCCLIN" moodCode="EVN">
    <realmCode xmlns="" code="CY"/>
    <typeId xmlns="" extension="POCD_HD000040" root="2.16.840.1.113883.1.3"/>
    <templateId xmlns="" root="1.3.6.1.4.1.12559.11.10.1.3.1.1.2"/>
    <templateId xmlns="" root="1.3.6.1.4.1.19376.1.5.3.1.1.1"/>
    <id extension="eDDiscId.CY202303170000002" root="2.16.840.1.113883.3.9143.3.1.3"/>
    <code code="DISCARD-60593-1" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.1" codeSystemName="LOINC" codeSystemVersion="2.59" displayName="Discard Medication Dispensed">
        <translation xmlns="" code="60593-1" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.1" codeSystemName="LOINC" displayName="eDispensation"/>
    </code>
    <title xmlns="">Discard Medication Dispensed</title>
    <effectiveTime xmlns="" value="20221130152655+0000"/>
    <confidentialityCode xmlns="" code="N" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.5.25" codeSystemName="Confidentiality" codeSystemVersion="913-20091020" displayName="normal"/>
    <languageCode xmlns="" code="en-GB"/>
    <setId xmlns="" extension="22015711.1" root="2.16.840.1.113883.3.9143.3.1.3"/>
    <recordTarget xmlns="">
        <patientRole classCode="PAT">
            <id extension="x1x2x2" root="2.16.840.1.113883.2.25.3.4.1.1.2"/>
            <addr>
                <country>GR</country>
                <streetAddressLine>ΕΓΝΑΤΙΑ 10</streetAddressLine>
            </addr>
            <telecom use="H" value="tel:12344"/>
            <patient>
                <name>
                    <given>MARINA</given>
                    <family>FILIP</family>
                </name>
                <administrativeGenderCode code="F" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.5.1" codeSystemName="AdministrativeGender" codeSystemVersion="913-20091020" displayName="Female"/>
                <birthTime value="20150101"/>
                <languageCommunication>
                    <templateId root="1.3.6.1.4.1.19376.1.5.3.1.2.1"/>
                    <languageCode code="en-GB"/>
                </languageCommunication>
            </patient>
        </patientRole>
    </recordTarget>
</ClinicalDocument>
```

Comment: minimum reproducable example?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Answer (score -1):

Your output depends on how you are generating the output. The `Document` object is an in memory representation of the XML document. Using JAXP API, you parsed the XML to create a `Document` object, then you iterated through the `Nodes` and modified your in memory `Elements` as per your requirement.

The output XML is a result of generating XML from your modified in memory `Document` object.

The missing part of generating output also has significant role on what you are seeing as output, because some aspects of output can be configured. Given you are dealing with JAXP API, this can be achieved by below code snippet. I put it as a method that prints the XML output to console, but this can be adapted as required. This did not generate `xmlns` attribute.

I have tested your code by printing the output using below method, and it did not have `xmlns` attributes in the output.

```
    static void printDoc(Document doc)  throws  Exception{
        Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");

        Writer out = new StringWriter();
        transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(out));

        System.out.println(out.toString());
    }
```

Having said this, I recommend you to use `XSLT` for your use case, if it is a project, that does not mandate you to use `Document` object to perform your transformations. May be you have to learn `XSLT`, but this is a correct tool for what you are trying to achieve. You can find lot of help on internet to get started and work your way through using XSLT.

Here is an example of how to put your transformations into XSLT. This has a few elements mapped (or transformed), but you can expand on this as you wish.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsL="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <!-- This is called an identity template, which means it copies all XML elements and attributes as it is into output XML -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="title">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:text>Discard Medication Dispensed</xsl:text>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="code/@code">
        <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('DISAORD-', .)"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="code/@displayName">
        <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
            <xsl:text>Discard Medication Dispensed</xsl:text>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As you can see the transformations are defined as templates for matching nodes and attributes. The `match` attribute of the `template` defines, to what elements of the input XML this transformation will be applied to.

Few basic things to understand here, are how to refer to a node or XML element and how to refer to an attribute and so on (what else you have for so on? well you can even refer to comment in the input XML, but don't worry too much about it for now).

The first template (called identity template) says for any `node()` or attribute referred as `@*`, copy that element and apply other matching templates for the child elements. If no other templates are defined then this template works as a recursion template (conceptually to understand), ultimately copying all input to output as it is, that is why the name `identity template`.

But, if you define other templates that match the particular elements in your input XML, then they take precedence, therefore you can tell what transformation to apply on that particular matching elements. This is where next simple templates come in.

```
    <xsl:template match="title">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:text>Discard Medication Dispensed</xsl:text>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```

matches the `title` node or XML element in your input document, and transformation is,

- copy the element name
- but change the text to `Discard Medication Dispensed`

Next template with a little variation is

```
    <xsl:template match="code/@code">
        <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('DISAORD-', .)"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
```

This will match for an attribute `code` of node `code` (basically `<code code='60593-1' ....>`. The transformation as defined inside the template will be applied. Based on what you have done in your `Document` object manipulation, this has been effectively prepended with `DISCARD-`. So I used the `concat` function. So this template says to

- copy the name of attribute as it is (`{name()}`, here refers to attribute name)
- concatenate `DISCARD-` and the value in input (referred by `.`)

Similarly the next template `<xsl:template match="code/@displayName">` , defining transformation of same `code` node, but for `displayName` attribute.

One important point is, the `XPath` value of `match` applies to all elements that matches in the XML. For example, the template `<xsl:template match="title">` applies to any XML element `title` anywhere in the XML in the hierarchy. Because in your specific input XML, it only occurs once and as a child of root element `ClinicalDocument`, it works as expected here. In case, if you have `title` in another part of the input XML, then this template will be applied that `title` also. In such cases, if this is not intended, then frame your XPath accordingly to refer to specific element, for example include `parent/title`, so this refers to `title` child under `parent` element. Depending upon input XML structure, this can be simple or complex. This complexity comes with input XML structure, not because of using XSLT.

You might have understood by now, that XML elements are referred just by there name `<code ....>` as `code` and attributes by prefix of `@` like `@displayName`. The slashes are used similar to file paths on disk. In XML world it is called `XPath`. If you can grasp the hierarchical structure or  parent-child structure of the XML document elements (I mean node, attribute, text, etc.), then defined path to specific parts in input XML as XPath.

Based on you have dealt with navigating through `Document` object using `Element` `Attribute`, etc at Java code level, I guess you can mentally map XML as hierarchical structure. Referring to parts of you XML in `XPath` should not be that difficult.

##### How is this XSLT plugged in into the code:

Very simple, mostly the same steps as in the `printDoc` method, but the transformer is created with our XSLT, instead of empty transformer (by empty, I mean `TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer()`, with no argument to `newTransformer` method).
So, this will change to `TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(new StreamSource(new File("path/to/xslt/file/dir/my-clinical-transformer.xslt")));`, assuming the XSLT is a separate file containing above template defintions. `StreamSource` has different constructors that take different types of arguments. You can work out how to use them if need to use different approach.

In a nutshell, you can replace your transformation Java code with below method call.

```
static void xsltTrans(Document doc)  throws  Exception{
        Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(new StreamSource(new File("src/com/mad/test/xml/trans.xslt")));

        Writer out = new StringWriter();
        transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(out));

        System.out.println(out.toString());
    }
```

The `doc` argument is the `Document` object created by parsing your input XML using `DocumentBuilder`.
If you have observed, the output properties of transformer are removed in Java code, as they are specified in the XSLT as `<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>`.

Just for information, the `xmlns` represents namespaces in the world of XML, somewhat like packages in Java. I guess you are not worried about that, as you wanted to eliminate `xmlns`, and that is OK.

I hope this helps!